# winsock always returning -1 on socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock

I'm trying to connect to my server on port 69 using winsock2.h. Everything appears to be compiling correctly but in a debugger maincommsock is always equal to -1. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working, and need help. Not very experienced with socket programming, and not sure what to do now!. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm not 100% sure what else to try. This is basically a function that establishes a connection on a socket, and sets connection to true, so that it can loop until it connects.

```
    int maincommsock;
    bool connection = false;

static void establishconn() {
    maincommsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (maincommsock == -1) {
        connection = false;
    }

    //OutputDebugString((LPCSTR)commservers[1]);

    /*
    struct hostent *host;
    if ((host = gethostbyname(SERV_ADDR)) == NULL) {
        connection = FALSE;
    }
    */
    SOCKADDR_IN sockaddr;
    sockaddr.sin_port = 69;
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    //sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    if (connect(maincommsock, (SOCKADDR *)(&sockaddr), sizeof(sockaddr)) != 1) {
        connection = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT

I used WSAStartup, and the error I'm currently getting is No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

EDIT 2

used htons on the port. It says the operation completed successfully but no connections show up on the server

EDIT 3

I'm going to test it on linux, to make sure that it is actually a server side error and not a problem with my code. I'll keep you guys updated.

Comment: Call `WSAGetLastError` to find out what the error is. https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror

Comment: Did you include `WSAStartup` before opening the socket?

Comment: `sockaddr.sin_port = htons(69);`

Comment: EDIT 2 is an unrelated issue as originally posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your error handling is a bit lacking.

First off, when an error does occur, STOP what you are doing. Right now, you are not stopping, you just move on to the next API call as if no error occured.

Second, your error handling on `connect()` is wrong. `connect()` returns 0 on success and -1 on failure, but you are checking its return value for `!= 1` so you are going to treat successes and failures the same way.

Try this instead:

```
static SOCKET establishconn(const char *addr, u_short port)
{
    SOCKET commsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (commsock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return INVALID_SOCKET;

    //OutputDebugStringA(addr);

    SOCKADDR_IN sockaddr = {};
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);

    if (sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        struct hostent *host = gethostbyname(addr);
        if (!host)
        {
            closesocket(commsock);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((u_long*) host->h_addr);
    }

    if (connect(commsock, (SOCKADDR &sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(commsock);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    return commsock;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
WSAStartup(...);
...
SOCKET maincommsock = establishconn("127.0.0.1", 69);
if (maincommsock != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    ...
    closesocket(maincommsock);
}
...
WSACleanup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Berkeley sockets require the address and port information to be presented in network byte order. Winsock follows this API:

> All of the data in the SOCKADDR_IN structure, except for the address family, must be specified in network-byte-order (big-endian).
>   <sub>[Windows Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr_in)</sub>

Use `htons()` to convert the port value from host to network byte order.

```
sockaddr.sin_port = htons(69);
```

`inet_addr()` already returns a value in network byte order.

Comment: I did that, and it says it completed successfully, so currently I'm trying to figure out if it's a server side problem.

Comment: @augboi666: Yes, but it would be a different question.

Comment: @augboi666 a bit confused, you saying there is a problem on creating a socket so how is that possible that the port is opened, are you trying to open a port on already existed socket?

Comment: @M.Sol I had a problem connecting the socket to the server. It always return -1 until I did WSAStartup and then htons on the port. Now I am believing that the problem is server side.

Comment: @augboi666: You may also want to `memset()` the `sockaddr` to zeros.

Comment: @augboi666 Ok got it, then please share with us part of server side otherwise can't help any further, everything seems good here.

Comment: @M.Sol: If the issue is now debugging the server, it is better to ask a new question.